# How to add EditText's value to the listview items?

Tags: java, android, arrays, listview

I want to add the content from an EditText to a ListView here is my code that dosen't work:

```
mass = userInput.getText().toString();
//fruits is a String[]
final List<String> fruits_list = new ArrayList<String(Arrays.asList(fruits));
final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context.getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, fruits_list);
fruits_list.add(mass);                                    
lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

The code adds the item to the listview but when the process is repeated it replaces the previously added string from the EditText.

Comment: Have you heard of a RecyclerView? They are the more advanced ListView with many more improvements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code appears to create a new `fruits_list` array every time you read the user's entry from the `EditText`.  This will result in only the latest entry being added to your list, replacing any previously added entries.

You need to create the array once (probably as a class member) and then update it each time you read the user input, e.g. something like:

```
    private ArrayList<String> fruits_list;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
    ...
    public void initialise(Context context) {
        fruits_list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(fruits));
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, fruits_list);
        lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
    ....
    public void getInput(
        mass = userInput.getText().toString();
        fruits_list.add(mass);
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Note the use of `arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to signal that new data has been added to the underlying data set.

As @Aaron says, you should also look at `RecyclerView` as a possible replacement, although that's a little bit more complicated to set up.